# create dummies from a column for a subset of data, which does't contains all the category value in that column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am handling a subset of the a large data set.

There is  a column named "type" in the dataframe. The "type" are expected to have values like [1,2,3,4].

In a certain subset, I find the "type" column only contains certain values like [1,4],like

```
 In [1]: df
 Out[2]:
          type
    0      1
    1      4
```

When I create dummies from column "type" on that subset, it turns out like this:

```
In [3]:import pandas as pd
In [4]:pd.get_dummies(df["type"], prefix = "type")
Out[5]:        type_1 type_4
        0        1       0
        1        0       1
```

It does't have the columns named "type_2", "type_3".What i want is like:

```
 Out[6]:        type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4
            0      1      0       0      0
            1      0      0       0      1
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df["type"])
        .reindex_axis([1,2,3,4], axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('type')
print (df1)
   type1  type2  type3  type4
0      1      0      0      0
1      0      0      0      1
```

Or [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) solution:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df["type"].astype('category', categories=[1, 2, 3, 4]), prefix='type')
print (df1)
   type_1  type_2  type_3  type_4
0       1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0       1
```

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is make the column `'type'` into a [**`pd.Categorical`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) and specify the `categories`

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.Categorical(df.type, [1, 2, 3, 4]), prefix='type')

   type_1  type_2  type_3  type_4
0       1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your post as `one-hot-encoding`, you may find `sklearn` module's [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) useful, in addition to pure Pandas solutions:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':[1,4]})
n_vals = 5

# one-hot encoding
encoder = OneHotEncoder(n_values=n_vals, sparse=False, dtype=int)
data = encoder.fit_transform(df.type.values.reshape(-1,1))

# encoded data frame
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['type_{}'.format(x) for x in range(n_vals)])

print(newdf)

   type_0  type_1  type_2  type_3  type_4
0       0       1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0       0       1
```

One advantage of using this approach is that `OneHotEncoder` easily produces sparse vectors, for very large class sets.  (Just change to `sparse=True` in the `OneHotEncoder()` declaration.)